# Variable length element sampling from list based on weights

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I want to select some items from a list depending on a given weight for each element. The length of the output is not known. This needs to be done a lot of times.

So, say I have a list of `[id, probability]` like `[[1, 0.2], [2, 0.3], [3, 0.45], [4, 0.05], [5,1.]]`, I want to get something like `[[1,3,5], [5], [3,5], [5], [1,2,4,5], ...]`

Here's my code to do so. It works, but it's pretty slow (the list is long, more than 10,000 elements of `[id, probability]`, and my result is thousands of `selection` long). Do you know of any way to make this (much) faster?

```
import numpy as np

items  = [[1, 0.2], [2, 0.3], [3, 0.45], [4, 0.05], [5,1.]]

combinations = []
for n in range(1000):
    selection = []
    for i in items:
        chosen = np.random.choice([True, False], p=[i[1], 1.-i[1]])
        if chosen:
            selection.append(i[0])
    combinations.append(selection)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize the sampling step as follows:

```
import numpy as np

# items  = [[1, 0.2], [2, 0.3], [3, 0.45], [4, 0.05], [5,1.]]
items = [(i, np.random.rand()) for i in range(1000)]

def sample_original(itms, n=1000):
  combinations = []
  for n in range(n):
      selection = []
      for i in items:
          chosen = np.random.choice([True, False], p=[i[1], 1.-i[1]])
          if chosen:
              selection.append(i[0])
      combinations.append(selection)


def sample_numpy(itms, n=1000):
  elts, probs = np.array(itms).T
  m = len(elts)
  return [elts[np.random.rand(m) < probs] for _ in range(n)]
```

The main observation is `np.random.rand(m) < probs` gives a random vector of `True/False` that selects elements of the original list with correct probabilities. This seems to be 1000x faster when there are 1000 items:

```
%timeit sample_numpy(items)
%timeit sample_original(items)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.6 ms per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 21.9 s per loop
```

If the probabilities are relatively high (resulting selections are not sparse), you might want to store the selection indicators in a 2D array for further performance gains.

Comment: This is positively brilliant. I didn't think of using the power of "np.where". Thank you.